# How can I down line before tag xml and after

Tags: php, xml

1. How can I down line before write the tag xml `<newWord>` to correct place ? and before tag `<Heb>`

my code rewrite xml file and when he add data he add to the first line all the data that he get from js and this line will be very length to big.

my Code:

```
<?php
  $wordH=$_GET['varHeb'];
  $wordE=$_GET['varEng'];
  $new_line = "\n";
  $doc='';

    if(!$doc)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        // we want a nice output
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $doc->load('Dictionary_user.xml');
    }
    $Dictionary_user = $doc->documentElement;
        $newWord = $doc->createElement('newWord');
   CHARSET=windows-1255"');

    $prop = $doc->createElement('Heb', $wordH);
    $newWord->appendChild($prop);
    $prop = $doc->createElement('Eng',$wordE);
    $newWord->appendChild($prop);


    $Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0)->parentNode->insertBefore($newWord,$Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0));
    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    $doc->save("Dictionary_user.xml");
echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

the bad resualt is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

`<Favorite_Word xml:lang="EN"><newWord><Heb>test1</Heb><Eng>test2</Eng></newWord><newWord><Heb>test1</Heb><Eng>test2</Eng></newWord><newWord><Heb>test1</Heb><Eng>test2</Eng></newWord>`test1test2`

```
<newWord>
    <Heb>cow</Heb>
    <Eng>Co</Eng>
</newWord>
<newWord>
    <Heb>Camel</Heb>
    <Eng>Ca</Eng>
</newWord>
<newWord>
    <Heb>Bull</Heb>
    <Eng>BUl</Eng>
</newWord>
```

the good resualt is:

```
<Favorite_Word xml:lang="EN">
<newWord>
    <Heb>test1</Heb>
    <Eng>test2</Eng>
</newWord>
<newWord>
    <Heb>cow</Heb>
    <Eng>Co</Eng>
</newWord>
<newWord>
    <Heb>Camel</Heb>
    <Eng>Ca</Eng>
</newWord>
<newWord>
    <Heb>Bull</Heb>
    <Eng>BUl</Eng>
</newWord>
```

Comment: Please add an example of the current result and an example of the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

`formatOutput` does not work when an already created DOM document is loaded. Usually via `load*()` method groups. But if you create it, It'll work.

You can do it using regex. And luckily [someone has done it](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2007/04/05/format-xml-with-php/) already.

XML is used for data exchange. If you can generate a valid xml document and other party can read it, its purpose is served. New lines, spaces are completely ignored. So the xml which you are calling bad is not Bad at all. Its completely okay.